# Issue accessing API endpoint on AWS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have build a two tier MEAN application with the authentication API backend hosted on AWS EC2 and the Angular front-end hosted on AWS S3 as a static site.

During development I had the auth backend served up using node/express on http://localhost:5719/. I had the front end served with a simple express server and sometimes I used MAMP. On the front-end I was accessing the backend with the following url:

.constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:5719/');

So for registration for example I would send an http post like:

http://localhost:5719/register

Everything worked well with all my routes. I hosted the backend on EC2 and applied the following settings:

Standard open access:
SSH
HTTP

I changed the server port to 80. From the front end I changed my API constant to the following which is the public DNS for the backend:

ec2-54-183-143-217.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

When I try to register from the front end I get the following 404 error in the console.

[image]

As you can see the post has the endpoint of the static site prepended to the public DNS. This is my guess as to why it does not work. I know very little about AWS but I suspect I have not set this up correctly and I have had a heck of a time finding information to help with this issue. Any assistance would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your API as a path not as a URL. Notice that you are not using http:// before your AWS EC2 address.

You need to put http or https in your API constant before your EC2 address as follow:

```
.constant('API_URL', 'http://ec2-54-183-143-217.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com');
```

or

```
.constant('API_URL', 'https://ec2-54-183-143-217.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com');
```

Comment: Thank you bro, that worked like a charm. Im celebrating my first backend application.

Comment: Cheers! Good to help you!